# C# open SFX Zip file

Tags: c#, zip, compression, .net-5, c#-ziparchive

I have the following code:

```
 using (var zip = new ZipArchive(passStream))
        {
            Pass = Json.Deserialize<Pass>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Json.ReadFully(zip.GetEntry("pass.json").Open())));
```

on the zip.GetEntry line I am getting the error:

InvalidDataException: Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.

I am fairly certain this is because the zip file being processed is a SFX Zip file (I opened in WinRar and that was the format it stated.)  Files that are standard Zip files open and process just fine. Also - if I double click on the SFX format zip file directly in windows, I get an error state 'The compressed folder XXXXXXXXXXX is invalid'.  If I double click on the standard zip files, they open fine.

Is there a built-in way to process SFX Zip files in C#.  I have explored the System.IO.Compression name space and did not see anything there.

If there is nothing in .net / C# is there a nuget package that can accomplish this.  I have looked at many of them and have not found any that specifically state they handle SFX Zip files.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

##UPDATED##
Based on the info @Shingo provided, I did the following:

```
        var bs = new BufferedStream(fs);
        int b;

        bs.Position = 0;

        while ((b = bs.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            if (b == 0x50)
            {
                var p = bs.Position;
                if (bs.ReadByte() == 0x4b &&
                   bs.ReadByte() == 0x03 &&
                   bs.ReadByte() == 0x04)
                {

                    //Copy from the current location (Positiong 6) to the new stream. This will remove the first 6 positions (index 0 -5) 
                    var tobj_NewStream = new MemoryStream();
                    bs.CopyTo(tobj_NewStream);
                    bs.Close();

                    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(tobj_NewStream))
                    {
                        var ti_Entries = zip.Entries.Count();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    bs.Position = p + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

The first several entries in the array after the SFX characters are 20,0,8,8,8,0.  After the new stream was created, I verified that is started with the series in index 0 - 5 and it did.  However, when I loaded the stream into the ZipArchive, I still could not see / access the entries in it.  I received the same error message I have been receiving:

System.IO.InvalidDataException
HResult=0x80131501
Message=Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.
Source=System.IO.Compression

Any other suggestions??

Comment: A sfx zip is a sfx program append with a zip file, so search the position of the sequence 50 4B 03 04 from the stream, then use the code at that position.

Comment: @shingo - Thank you for the report.  So I convert the stream to a byte array and search for 50 4B 03 04 in the array and then take all the data after that?  Any info or example would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: No, take all the data from 0x50 till the end. For a large file or difficult to read the whole file, you can do search with a BufferedStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example you may have a try.

```
var bs = new BufferedStream(filestream);
int b;

while((b = bs.ReadByte()) != -1)
{
    if(b == 0x50)
    {
        var p = bs.Position;
        if(bs.ReadByte() == 0x4b &&
           bs.ReadByte() == 0x03 &&
           bs.ReadByte() == 0x04)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            filestream.Position = p - 1;
            filestream.CopyTo(ms);

            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms))
            {
                //...
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            bs.Position = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- I am going to try this now.

Comment: I tried this -- inside the using (var zip ...... block I added a line to see if I could access the entries in the zip file using var ti_Entries = zip.Entries.Count();  However on this line I get the same error I have been getting - System.IO.InvalidDataException
  Message=Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.
  Source=System.IO.Compression

Comment: Ok there are 2 problems, first is insignificant the position is not set correctly, the main problem is ZipArchive always tries to read from the beginning of the stream, so this approach cannot work. You still have to copy the rest content to a new stream for ZipArchive  to read.

Comment: ok that was kind of what I thought -- let me try again.

Comment: I did the code you suggested and posted it in an update to my question along with the results -- still the same error when I attempt to access the entries in the ZipArchive.

Comment: You missed this line `filestream.Position = p - 1`, and note that I've fixed the position in the `else` block to `bs.Position = p`